# How To Set AFHTTPRequestOperation completionQueue to current queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, afnetworking, grand-central-dispatch

I have a layer of abstraction between AFNetworking and the rest of my iOS app. And I have an issue where sometimes `- (void)setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:` **gets called from inside a block on the main thread**: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)` and **other times inside this block on another thread**: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), block)`

But unless I set the completionQueue to the current queue, the completion block get's thrown back to the main thread. However, I need the code to run on the thread from which I was previously running on.

Is there a good way to achieve this? Apparently dispatch_get_current_queue() is deprecated and was never appropriate for production code anyway.

EDIT: realize this probably won't work with a concurrent queue since it doesn't guarantee same thread. So instead I'll create a custom `dispatch_queue_t myCustomQueue;
myCustomQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyCustomQueue", NULL);` Which I believe will put me back on the same thread. EDIT2: I guess I was wrong, It still puts it on another thread. Lame. I need it to be the same one.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered empirically, other than the main queue and main thread, there is no reliable relationship between GCD queues and OS threads. If you want thread affinity here, you could set `completionQueue` to a global concurrent queue, and then have the completion block use `- performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` to marshal the real work to a different thread.  Imagine something like this:

```
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, id responseObject) {

    dispatch_block_t realSuccessCompletion = ^{
        NSAssert([[NSThread currentThread] isEqual: intendedThread], @"Wrong thread");

        // Do real work.
    };

    // Send it to the thread you want it run on.
    [(id)realSuccessCompletion performSelector: @selector(invoke) onThread: intendedThread withObject: nil waitUntilDone: NO];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, NSError *error) {

    dispatch_block_t realFailureCompletion = ^{
        NSAssert([[NSThread currentThread] isEqual: intendedThread], @"Wrong thread");

        // Do real work.
    };

    // Send it to the thread you want it run on.
    [(id)realFailureCompletion performSelector: @selector(invoke) onThread: intendedThread withObject: nil waitUntilDone: NO];
}];
```

This takes advantage of the fact that blocks behave like Objective-C objects which respond to the selector `-invoke`.  Note that this also relies on the intended thread being long-lived and having a run loop, although if the thread were ephemeral, then it's not clear why you would want to run things on the same thread later.